# Nested IF Statement C++ Syntax

Tags: c++

Is my syntax correct for this nested `if` statement?

I am trying to run through all values.  But it does not seem to provide any outputs is all values are not equal to 1.

I am using Xcode so some of the code may differ than in VS.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int haveMoney, haveTime, amHungry, restaurantOpen, haveTransportation;
    
    cout << "Yes = 1,  2 = No" << endl << endl;
    
    cout << "Do I have money?" << endl;
    cin >> haveMoney;
    cout << "Do I have time?" << endl;
    cin >> haveTime;
    cout << "Am I hungry?" << endl;
    cin >> amHungry;
    cout << "Are they open?" << endl;
    cin >> restaurantOpen;
    cout << "Do I have transportation?"<< endl;
    cin >> haveTransportation;
    

    if ((haveMoney == 1) && (haveTime == 1) && (amHungry == 1) && (restaurantOpen == 1) && (haveTransportation == 1)){
        cout << "Enjoy your McDonalds!" << endl << endl;
        
        if (haveMoney == 2){
            cout << "You're broke, so you can't have McDonalds" << endl ;
        
        if (haveTime == 2){
            cout << "You don't have enough time to go to McDonalds!" << endl ;
        
        if (amHungry == 2){
            cout << "Why are you even thinking about McDonalds, you're not hungry!" << endl ;
                
        if (restaurantOpen == 2){
            cout << "McDonalds is closed, tough luck." << endl ;
                    
        if (haveTransportation == 2){
            cout << "You have no transportation to get to McDonalds." << endl ;
        
        
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (haveMoney == 2){` could never be true because to enter the outer `if ((haveMoney == 1) && (haveTime == 1) && (amHungry == 1) && (restaurantOpen == 1) && (haveTransportation == 1)){`  haveMoney has to be 1. Same reason for the rest of the nested if () statements.

Comment: Those should NOT be nested if statements.  They should be sequential if/else if statements.  The inner clauses are not subsets of the outer clause.

Comment: Note: if the program compiles the syntax is correct. Unfortunately the logic may still be incorrect.

Comment: Note: if the program is written using nothing but Standard C++ the compiler used should  not matter. If it does, welp, you just found a compiler bug.

Comment: Is there a syntax that would work with a nested IF statement?

Comment: Indenting (adding whitespace before a line) does not affect nesting of `if` statements.   If you want to nest multiple statements (e.g. in an `if()` block, some statement followed by another `if()` )then you need to group things in a block statement.   The start and end of a block statement is indicated by  `{` and `}` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You need chained `if-else-if` statements, not nested `if` statements.  This does what you expect.  Note that I have omitted the curly braces for the `if` statements for ease of typing.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int haveMoney, haveTime, amHungry, restaurantOpen, haveTransportation;
    
    cout << "Yes = 1,  2 = No" << endl << endl;
    
    cout << "Do I have money?" << endl;
    cin >> haveMoney;
    cout << "Do I have time?" << endl;
    cin >> haveTime;
    cout << "Am I hungry?" << endl;
    cin >> amHungry;
    cout << "Are they open?" << endl;
    cin >> restaurantOpen;
    cout << "Do I have transportation?"<< endl;
    cin >> haveTransportation;
 
    if ((haveMoney == 1) && (haveTime == 1) && (amHungry == 1) && (restaurantOpen == 1) && (haveTransportation == 1))
        cout << "Enjoy your McDonalds!" << endl << endl;

    else if (haveMoney == 2)
        cout << "You're broke, so you can't have McDonalds" << endl ;

    else if (haveTime == 2)
        cout << "You don't have enough time to go to McDonalds!" << endl ;

    else if (amHungry == 2)
        cout << "Why are you even thinking about McDonalds, you're not hungry!" << endl ;

    else if (restaurantOpen == 2)
        cout << "McDonalds is closed, tough luck." << endl ;

    else if (haveTransportation == 2)
        cout << "You have no transportation to get to McDonalds." << endl ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you everybody.

Comment: Is there a syntax that would work with a nested IF statement?

Comment: @SamuelCulper it does not matter how many nested IF-statements you have, as long as they follow the same set of rules, e.g. `if (...) {} else if (...) {} else {}`. And inside the curly bracket scopes you may recurse: `if (...) { if (...) { if (...) {}}}`.

NOTE: If there is no curly bracket scope following an IF-statment, then only the first instruction following will be included as part of that IF branch. Example: `if (...) do_maybe(); do_always();`. This is a common pitfall.

Comment: No, because the questions you want to ask are not nested.  It's EITHER "all conditions are met" OR "one of the conditions is not met".  The problem is not a nested problem.